# Replace entire web.config with NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Is there a way to have nuget replace the entire web.config when you install a package?

Let's say I create a custom package which contains a web.config. I want to install this custom package and have it completely overwrite the existing web.config in a given project instead of merging like it does by default. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me you could use a [XML-Document-Transform](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations) and `xdt:Transform="Replace"` the `configuration` section like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xdt:Transform="Replace" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        ...
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I haven't done this myself, and I'm not sure that a transform can be applied to the `configuration` element. Let me know if that doesn't work and I'll delete this answer.